# Step by step instruction for installing Illustrator in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

i am totally new on Ubuntu and want to install the Illustrator on my laptop so any one can guide me step by step how to do it.

Comment: Illutrator? Like Adobe Illustrator? Windows software... not going to happen (and to anyone reading: no wine is not acceptable ;) ) Try "inkscape" it is in the repositories.

Comment: my friend recommended "Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor" is this a same one.

Comment: Yes its the same, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install inkscape` to install it. Or use the Ubuntu Software Center. [More info about Inkscape (Tutorials, Videos etc.)](http://www.inkscape.org/en/)

Comment: IT WORKS SUPERB

Answer (score -1):

you can use playonlinux software for run Adobe software or other soft on Linux [EX : ubuntu]

softwer link : [playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html)

tutorial : [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amCuGfkGmzI)

[image]